# Twitter bootstrap nav class. Data-toggle stop menus working

Tags: html, tabs, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, nav

I have a problem with Twitter Bootstrap's class="nav."

When I include "data-toggle='tab'", none of my menu items function.

(BTW: If I remove data-toggle, the first option does not work, but the rest will i.e. if data-toggle is removed, Google does NOT work, but Bing and Bing2 will, and Yahoo won't work, but CNN and Weather do)

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body>

        <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="http://www.google.com" data-toggle="tab">Google</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.bing.com" data-toggle="tab">Bing</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.bing.com" data-toggle="tab">Bing2</a></li>

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More choices <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com" data-toggle="tab">Yahoo</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://www.cnn.com" data-toggle="tab">CNN</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://www.accuweather.com">Weather</a></li> <!-- NOTE data-toggle removed -->
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please would you check your console, there is an error on li element : **Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: (http://www.bing.com)**

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Looks ok to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example: http://jsbin.com/ujujub/1/edit

Three things:

- Remember to include `bootstrap-tab.js`
- Write a script responsible for handling navigation from tab to tab
- The links should not point directly to the content of your sites, but rather to the the ID of divs that wrap the content of your sites.