# Click link is not working with thymeleaf

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I use spring boot, thymeleaf and bootstrap.

When i go to my vehicle page, I want to display all vehicle

```
@GetMapping("/vehicle")
    public String getVehiclesList(final Model model) {
        List<vehicle> vehicles = vehicleService.getAll();
        model.addAttribute("vehicles", vehicles);
        return "vehicle";
    }
```

I have a fragment name: menu

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tab" class="active">
        <a href="#">Sport</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tab">
        <a href="/vehicle" th:href="@{/vehicle}">Vehicule</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on vehicle, nothing happen...

but if i put vehicle in the url, that work.

Seem like bootstrap event is not working

Edit

code of the vehicle file who is not displayed when i click link

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html th:lang="${#locale.language}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head th:replace="fragments/head :: head-css"/>
    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2 column menu_side">
                    <div th:replace="fragments/menu :: left-menu"/>
                </div>

                <div id="main" class="col-sm-10 column">    
                    <div role="tabpanel">
                        <form th:action="@{/vehicle-layout}"  method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="definition">Pick a base vehicle</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="vehicle">
                                    <option th:value="NULL" selected="selected" > -- select the vehicle --</option>
                                    <option th:each="vehicle : ${vehicles}" th:value="${vehicle.id}" th:text="${vehicle.name}"></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div> 
        </div>       
        <div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer"/>

    </body>
</html>
```

Edit 2, if it remove

data-toggle="tab"

in the menu, that working... don't really understand why.

Comment: `<li th:each="vehicle : ${vehicles}"><span th:text="${vehicle}">Vehicle Name</span></li>`  Also, by convention, your classes should start with a capital letter.

Comment: Delete the href attribute from your link, you only need the th:href attribute. I don't think the problem has anything to do with Bootstrap.

Comment: @bphilipnyc not related... view vehicle is just not displayed.... if i type directly in the url bar: http://localhost:8080/vehicle, I see vehicule... but not when i click on the link from the menu

Comment: @tamás-g, change nothing... also it's 100% ok to write something like <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: @bphilipnyc, view is not displayed when i click...  html displayed is for the menu ... when i click vehicle entry of the menu.... vehicule view is supposed to be displayed...  if i put localhost:8080/vehicle, in the url bar, i see the vehicles..

Comment: Why would it be ok to refer for two different things with two different approach with one link? Also, bootstrap has nothing to do with links, bootstrap is just for visual styling.

Comment: Can you explain whenever you click "Vehicule" link. Then is URL changing in browser? And can you please provide the HTML of "vehicle" page?

Comment: @TamásG.  seem like something related to bootstrap... because when i remove data-toggle that working...

Comment: @Zico see edit 2, no when i click url is not changing

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/q/13110025/1125284 would help you

Answer (score 0):

I used technic available here

http://nixmash.com/post/bootstrap-navbar-highlighting-in-thymeleaf

that work fine.

Don't know if it possible to do it with standard bootstrap ...